# CV_8UC1 (Error-215) in function adaptiveThreshold

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, python-imaging-library

In this code we are preprocessing an RGB image for Tesseract OCR using tools such as cv2, NumPy and PIL. When this code is executed in the Python 2.7.13 Shell, I recieve the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Automation\OCR\images\OCR_Preprocessing_ RGB.py", line 23, in <module> cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2) error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1446: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::adaptiveThreshold
```

Here is the code that error generated from. I have marked lines of code where I think the problem may be.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

# Loads the image then enhances it
image = Image.open('teleCapture.png')
contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
img = contrast.enhance(2)
img = np.asarray(img)
r,g,b,a = cv2.split(img) // I know the issue is here, I have too many channels for an RGB image or I am merginf them wrong.
contrast = cv2.merge([b,g,r]) //"Contrast" was used as a src during Thresholding, is this what it should be?

# Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding //The problem may be within the thresholding, does this thresholding function only work using grayscale images?
th1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(contrast,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
# Otsu's thresholding
ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(contrast,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(contrast,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# writes enhanced and thresholded img
cv2.imwrite('preprocessedTeleCapture.png', th2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threshold method need 1 channel image as input, and you give 3 channel, that's the problem shown in error message.

Comment: Okay, @AndreySmorodov can you give me an example using the above code?

Comment: Just fix code and it will work, I did point what is wrong there. I don't know what is this, and what it should do, apply threshold each channel, or convert it to gray and then threshold, may be something else? There everywhere the same mistake. I don't know what did you mean in this code.

Comment: with one channel I get error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Automation\OCR\images\OCR_Preprocessing_ RGB.py", line 19, in <module>
    contrast = cv2.merge([x])
TypeError: mv is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: merge makes 3 channel image from 3 separate single channel images. method split splits image by channels producing n separate images from milti-channel image. And you trying to merge one channel, of cause you got an error.